# Store specific data related to users

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Scenario - need to store on blockchain specific data related to users.

- potentially very large number of users
- data should not be changed in the future, and that's the whole point to make it immutable
- smart contract should have ability to check it for any user at any time
- data size to store per user is small
- the data should not be easy to find or interpret on blockchain for general public

From my understanding there are 2 ways:

---

**Store in transaction's data**

- cheaper to store
- if user personal information is stored in a offchain database, the data on blockchain can reference it by primary key. Database can
  store all transactions for specific user for fast search

**Questions**

- Does having part of data stored offchain beat the purpose of using
  blockchain in terms of if database is somehow lost/corrupt then data
  stored in a contract becomes useless?
- Is there a point of using Swarm/IPFS instead of regular database? what benefits it would have?
- Can a smart contract easily access a transaction's data? is it free or not?

---

**Store in smart contract's data**

- expensive to store
- info is easy to find within contract's data structures

**Questions**

Since contract's data can be modified, it looses the immutability benefit? can the changes to contract's data be tracked on blockchain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of all of your scenarios, *"the data should not be easy to find or interpret on blockchain for general public"* will probably be the most complex part.

Let's go over each option.

---

**Store in transaction's data**

- **(True)** cheaper to store
- **(True)** if user personal information is stored in a offchain database, the data on blockchain can reference it by primary key. Database can store all transactions for specific user for fast search

**Questions**

- Does having part of data stored offchain beat the purpose of using blockchain in terms of if database is somehow lost/corrupt then data stored in a contract becomes useless?

> **(True)** *Just like anything that indexed with a key, if the key leads to lost or corrupt data, then the key is useless.*

- Is there a point of using Swarm/IPFS instead of regular database? what benefits it would have?

> *Swarm/IPFS would allow you to distribute the database in a similar fashion like the blockchain so there's not a single point of failure. Encryption/decryption would have to be handled end-to-end if security is an issue.*

- Can a smart contract easily access a transaction's data? is it free or not?

> *Easily, no. You'd essentially have to use an oracle (which also could handle decryption if you go that route) to transfer the data to the contract itself.*

---

**Store in smart contract's data**

- **(True)** expensive to store
- **(True)** info is easy to find within contract's data structures

**Questions**

- Since contract's data can be modified, it loses the immutability benefit?

> *Immutability and modification are 2 different concepts in this scenario. Once written on the blockchain, the data is immutable...but a value of a storage pointer can be updated with new immutable data. Data is never really changed, but the pointer is updated to a new storage value. Update is probably a better word in this case than modification.*

- Can the changes to contract's data be tracked on blockchain?

> *Based on what I said above, yes, all updates can be tracked.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate a bit on "Encryption/decryption would have to be handled end-to-end if security is an issue", this part is not clear to me.

Comment: @Serge Well, for the blockchain, and IFPS/Swarm, data continuity has to be verifiable but you can get away with using something like GPG encryption on IFPS. This blog, "[Learn to securely share files on the blockchain with IPFS!](https://medium.com/@mycoralhealth/learn-to-securely-share-files-on-the-blockchain-with-ipfs-219ee47df54c)" is a good example article on what that process looks like.